# Проблема с RecyclerView в PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-viewpager

В общем у меня есть фрагмент с ViewPager и TabLayout. на страничках есть фрагменты с текстом и фрагменты с RecyclerView. так вот при первом запуске фрагмента все подгружается нормально. После же выхода из фрагмента кнопкой назад и запуска заново, Фрагмент с RecyclerView перестает работать.

Код:
Фрагмент:

```
package com.starikov.gidtj.NewTowns;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.starikov.gidtj.R;
import com.starikov.gidtj.TownLists.Dushanbe.HistoryOfDushanbe;
import com.starikov.gidtj.TownLists.Dushanbe.MuseumsOfDushanbe;
import com.starikov.gidtj.TownLists.Dushanbe.ParksAndMonumentsOfDushanbe;
import com.starikov.gidtj.TownLists.Dushanbe.WalkingTourOfDushanbe;
import com.starikov.gidtj.adapters.TownsPagerAdapter;

public class Dushanbe extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater infalater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return infalater.inflate(R.layout.dushanbe, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().setTitle("Душанбе");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        View view = getView();
        assert view != null;

        final TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("История Душанбе"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Музеи"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Парки и памятники"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Пешая прогулка по Душанбе"));

        final ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        Fragment list[] = {
                new HistoryOfDushanbe(),
                new MuseumsOfDushanbe(),
                new ParksAndMonumentsOfDushanbe(),
                new WalkingTourOfDushanbe()
        };
        final TownsPagerAdapter adapter = new TownsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), list);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Адаптер:

```
package com.starikov.gidtj.adapters;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TownsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Fragment mFragments[];

    public TownsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Fragment fragments[]) {
        super(fm);
        this.mFragments = fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(viewGroup, position, object);
    }
}
```

Фрагмент с RecyclerView:

```
package com.starikov.gidtj.TownLists.Dushanbe;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.starikov.gidtj.R;
import com.starikov.gidtj.adapters.FlowRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.starikov.gidtj.info.Museum;

public class MuseumsOfDushanbe extends Fragment {

    private CharSequence[] museumNames;
    private CharSequence[] museumDescriptions;
    private int[] museumImages;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RecyclerView formulaRecycler = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.museums_of_dushanbe, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Музеи Душанбе");
        setInfo(Museum.dushanbe_museums);
        FlowRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new FlowRecyclerViewAdapter(museumNames, museumDescriptions, museumImages);
        formulaRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        formulaRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return formulaRecycler;
    }

    private void setInfo(Museum[] museums) {
        museumNames = new CharSequence[museums.length];
        museumDescriptions = new CharSequence[museums.length];
        museumImages = new int[museums.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < museums.length; ++i) {
            museumNames[i] = museums[i].getName();
            museumDescriptions[i] = museums[i].getDescription();
            museumImages[i] = museums[i].getImageID();
        }
    }

}
```

Прошу помощи, а то уже битый час бьюсь. Если нужно еще кинуть какой нибудь код, скину только скажите.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я не уверен в правильности решения, но попробуйте в метод viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(); передать значение равное количеству фрагментов в адаптере. Это позволит не пересоздавать их постоянно. Также, если вам известно количество фрагментов в адаптере ViewPager, рекомендуется использовать класс FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: @ВладСапожников setOffscreenPageLimit ставил 4 ( как и количество фрагментов ) не помогло. Ща посмотрю в сторрону FragmentPagerAdapter.

Comment: @ВладСапожников FragmentPagerAdapter тоже непомог

Comment: Что значит перестает работать? Скиньте стэктрейс ошибки, если есть

Comment: @Jarvis_J ошибки нету, приложение не вылетает. Просто при повторрном запуске фрагмента, RecyclerView не отображает элементы. Он просто пуст

Comment: @Jarvis_J ошибки нету, приложение не вылетает. Просто при повторрном запуске фрагмента, RecyclerView не отображает элементы. Он просто пуст

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте не хранить массив с фрагментами и при выходе с фрагмента с ViewPager вручную удалять фрагменты из FragmentManager.

Или можно еще getChildFragmentManager() вместо getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()